# Add as many underscores to a list as the len(word) number is and each underscore is a separate item in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python and I need help with this code

```
underscore_list = []
underscore_list.append(len(main_word) * "_")
print(underscore_list)
```

(`main_word` is an input from the user.)

The output is `["_____"]` (as many underscores as the `len(main_word)` number is) but I need it to be like `["_", "_"...]`, so the underscores are separate items in the list.

Comment: Use extend instead of append?

Comment: Did you mean `underscore_list = ['_'] * len(main_word)`?

Comment: Or to play with underscores: `lst = ['_' for _ in range(len(word))]`

Comment: See how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
underscore_list = len(main_word) * ['_']
```

Or:

```
underscore_list = [c for c in len(main_word) * '_']
```

Or even:

```
underscore_list = list(len(main_word) * '_')
```

Answer (score 0):

You Could Try The Following Code:

```
underscore_list = []
main_word = input("Enter A Word:\n")
for x in range(len(main_word)):
    underscore_list.append("_")

print(underscore_list)
```

It Uses The `append` function to add the underscores. Then, we use a loop that repeats `len(main_word)` times. SO if the word was `"word"`, the loop would see that word is 4 letters long, and then append `"_"` 4 times to the list, giving us: `["_", "_", "_", "_"]`

Or Even:
`underscore_list = ["_"] * len(main_word)`

`["_" for _ in range(len(word))]` also works.

Do Any Of Those Work For You?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick function that will take any word (string) input and output a string of underscores with the same length as the input string.

```
def convert_word_to_uscore(myword):
    tmp = ""
    for i in range(len(myword)):
        tmp = tmp+"_"
    return tmp

convert_word_to_uscore("myverylongword")

out: '______________'
```

Edit: misread OP's question. Is this what you want?

```
def convert_word_to_uscore(myword):
    tmp = []
    for i in range(len(myword)):
        tmp.append('_')
    return tmp

convert_word_to_uscore("myverylongword")

out: ['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
```

Comment: Your output is exactly what the OP is producing now, but doesn't want.

Comment: Is the new edit what you are looking for?

Comment: eh why not... maybe someone else will find it useful  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is you're creating a string of n underscores like:

```
main_word = 'four'
len(main_word) * "_"
>>> "____"
```

Then this is added to the list resulting in:

```
main_word = 'four'
underscore_list = []    
underscore_list.append( len(main_word) * "_" )
print(underscore_list)
>>> ["____"]
```

You have a couple options to solve. Since a string is a list of characters in python, you could use list.extend which iterates over a list (the list of characters in your case) and appends each item to the original list.

```
underscore_list = []
main_word = 'four'
underscore_list.extend(len(main_word) * "_")
print(underscore_list)
>>> ['_', '_', '_', '_']
```

Another option is to create a list with one underscore character inside it and then duplicate that n number of times.

```
print(['_'] * 4)
>>> ['_', '_', '_', '_']
```

You could save this directly to your variable without append/extend.

```
main_word = 'four'
underscore_list = len(main_word) * ["_"]
print(underscore_list)
>>> ['_', '_', '_', '_']
```